# How do I sign into an unconfirmed Nintendo account?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I've reformatted my 3DS and I forgot to confirm my email for my account and I lost everything I've bought, is there a way to sign into this account?

Answer (score 1):

You call Nintendo support before you do anything else and explain the situation. They may be able to help you get your purchases back and recover your account.